# A real world project using microservices architecture

Tags: node.js, architecture, microservices

Anyone knows an open source project that is on microservices architecture? I need a more real app that has addressed cross-cutting concerns,etc not just an educational sample.

Please introduce if you know any. Especially if it's on Node.js or C#.net stack.

Thanks

Comment: Check out Airbnb's smartstack. While (obviously) Airbnb doesn't release the source code for their website they have released all their frameworks. Google it and search for it on github. Warning: it's a lot of reading because it isn't a single piece of software (the HAProxy thing alone took me a while to read through).

Comment: The basic take-away I got was, very few things are cross-cutting concerns with microservices since different parts may be implemented in different languages using different libraries. Instead, things are just services (even stuff like logging)

Comment: Thanks guys. I've googled it and searched for it in Github but couldn't find any REAL app that's why I'm asking here

Comment: Netflix is a pretty good example

Comment: Yeah but the problem being we don't have access to their code. is it a public repository? As I didn't find any of the famous microservices (netflix, spotify, ebay, ...) in the github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are little to no open source projects out there using this pattern!

There are however many great framworks/toolchains to help you implement it:

- If you like GO then you're gonna like **Go-Kit**
- If you like C# you might have a look at **servicestack.net**
- as for other languages/toolchains I'm not very well informed but there are many frameworks out there that can help you building microservices in almost every major language.

That said: The main reason for this lack of open source micro service systems is probably that most open source project keep a very narrow track of use cases that they cover to stay generic and reusable. This stands in contrast to what commercial backend systems have to provide - which is myriad of usually very specific business services which will probably never be public since they contain the companies competitive advantages and business critical knowledge! Most large exponents of the micro service pattern (like Netflix, Spotify and SoundCloud) have however open sourced the tools and frameworks they build/used to get the services orchestrated, coordinated, synchronized, health checked, list, balanced, scaled etc...

To give you some general pointer towards micro services in general [Martin Fowler](https://www.google.com/search?q=martin%20fowler%20microservices&oq=martin%20fowler&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.3443j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has some great resources. Also a good reference are the talks of [Peter Bourgon on Micro services](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd4DE6D6o94).

Comment: Thanks mate! yeah that makes sense

Comment: you can flag this as the answer if it helped, so it helps others too ;-)